# How to call getBaseContext() on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I have this method which can be called from normal Activity:

```
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

The problem is I cannot call `getBaseContext()` in Fragment, how can I to do that? Or with what do I need to replace the `getBaseContext()` from a Fragment class?

Comment: Why are you using `getBaseContext()` in the first place?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29), which returns the activity associated with a fragment.
The activity is a context *(since Activity extends Context)*.

But you can use it after the fragment is attached to the activity..

Answer (score 13):

use `getActivity().getBaseContext();`